# Another Javascript Question About One Line of Code

Tags: javascript

I've been itching to ask this question: Why, when I open js code from a website online, is the code written all on 1 line? Is this supposed to be some security thing?

Comment: [Minification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minification_(programming)) and/or [obfuscation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obfuscation_(software))

Comment: Sometimes for reasons of obfuscation, but mostly just saving bandwidth. If you're running a large-scale site, every byte counts.

Comment: [https://www.imperva.com/learn/performance/minification/](https://www.imperva.com/learn/performance/minification/)

Comment: Very helpful comments. Thank you all for clearing my confusion. I now see the world different.